# How to replace "_" and "-" in my URL string using Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a name that will always be in this format with varying numbers of _ and - symbols.

e.g. CWTE_4_3-My_Friendly_Name
e.g. Inette_5-Friendly_Again

I need to convert these in my sharepoint designer workflow to replace the "_" and the "-" markes with "%2D" and "%5F" respectively.

I tried to do this in my Infopath form but Translate only works across one character limit. so I could replace "-" with "{" but not with "%2D".

Can I do this in Sharepoint Designer? I don't know if I can because the number of the _ and - varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the solution was here: spdwfextensions.codeplex.com using the Replace() function from the Invoke C# action in SPD. THANKS!!! – April D.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a workflow why don't you use a calculated column in the list itself?  Go to the list > Click on Settings > Create Column.  For the column name enter "Last Name", for the type of column choose calculated.  For your formula use the following (replace name with the name of the column where the full name is):

=LEFT(Name,(SEARCH(",",Name,1)-1))

Then to get the first name create another calculated column called "First Name" and use the following formula (again replace Name with your name column):

=RIGHT(Name,(LEN(Name)-SEARCH(" ",Name,1)))

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/ac908be0-9fe9-45aa-beae-0e7a968be90e/

check above link it helps......

Comment: How does that solve the question?

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, besides mentioning of calculated columns

Comment: Try with Custom Event Receiver or JQurey........

Comment: that would work if i knew there were only 2 names. but there aren't. there could be 3 or 4 or 5. and there could be an "-" or not. i need a 'loop' function and i don't think one exists for designer.

Comment: OK so the solution was here:  http://spdwfextensions.codeplex.com/ using the Replace() function from the Invoke C# action in SPD.  THANKS!!!

Comment: this one is before i mention my first comment. Read full Comment                                             http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/ac908be0-9fe9-45aa-beae-0e7a968be90e/